# mvn site command not working - generates css and images not html

Tags: java, maven

I am having a strange problem with maven. To create a java project I am using the `mvn archetype:generate` command. This creates a directory structure with a java source file `App.java` and a test file. This is done by selecting the default option then entering in folder and package information.

Now I have a bare bones java project generated by Maven. My problem is I was trying to generate a website of this using the `mvn site` command and then finding that nothing was generated in terms of html. The only things that were generated was a css folder and an images folder.

Does anyone know why there were no html files created? This is normally not a problem.

I am using OS-X for this with Java 1.6 if that helps debug this issue.

All the best,

user_loser

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you follow these steps you should succeed to generate a maven site. I've tested it with Maven 3.0.4 and Maven 3.3.1

- Create a fresh new directory

  `mkdir mavenTest`
- Go inside it

  `cd mavenTest`
- Generate a project [using the quickstart archetype](http://maven.apache.org/archetype/maven-archetype-plugin/examples/generate-batch.html)

  `mvn archetype:generate -B -DarchetypeGroupId=org.apache.maven.archetypes -DarchetypeArtifactId=maven-archetype-quickstart -DarchetypeVersion=1.1 -DgroupId=com.company -DartifactId=project -Dversion=1.0-SNAPSHOT -Dpackage=com.company.project`
- Go inside the project directory

  `cd project`
- Generate the website

  `mvn site`
- Look at it

  `ls target/site/`

.

```
css                          images                  project-info.html
dependencies.html            index.html              project-summary.html
dependency-convergence.html  plugin-management.html
dependency-info.html         plugins.html
```

Comment: I tried this. It did not work for me. I have a feeling this would work on Linux Ubuntu or Windows though. Thank-you for the detailed reply. I like your command line switches to generate the Java project without going through the options given by Maven. My firewall settings alerted me for a half a second. I have a hypothesis this is partly to do with why no .html pages were generated. I only see an `images` and a `css` directory under the `target/site` directory. Thanks again for the help. :D

Comment: Try to turn off your firewall. If you use the same Maven version and follow these steps it should work. Can you also publish your build log?

Comment: I was using an older version of Maven 3.0.3 with Java 1.6 - I am updating to java 1.7 and Maven 3.3.1. Turning off my firewall may work with my older environment but this is pretty terrible in terms of computer security - not to mention scary in terms of info security. I am going to try running your Maven script with this new environment. :D

Comment: This works with java1.7 with Maven 3.3.1 on OS-X 10.7.5 with the firewall up to very high settings! Thanks for the help @Ortomala Lokni